# Finding an upper bound for $\frac{1}{r^n} \int_{||\vec{u}|| \le n 2^n C} e^{-\pi ||(\vec{x} + \vec{u})/r||^2} d \vec{u}$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I am trying find an upper bound for the following integral, I know the expression is less than $1$, and I would prefer to find a bound that looks like $\frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}$. Where $f(n)$ is any function in $n$.

The integral is: $$\frac{1}{r^n} \int_{||\vec{u}|| \le n 2^n C} e^{-\pi ||(\vec{x} + \vec{u})/r||^2} d \vec{u}$$

**We also know the following:**

$n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\vec{x}$ and $\vec{u}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

$C$ and $r$ are just constants.

$||\vec{x}|| \ge \sqrt{n} r$

$r > 2^{2n} C$

I am a bit stumped so any hints or tips would he gladly appreciated.

I've tried doing the substitution $\vec{y} = \vec{u} + \vec{x}$ and integrate over $\mathbb{R^n}$ instead of the ball, but the bound is $1$ in that case which is too high.

I've also tried using the reverse triangle inequality $-||\vec{x}+\vec{u}||^2 \leq -(||\vec{x} - \vec{u}||)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated to you in chat, the most productive approach seems to be to make the change of variables $\vec y = \frac 1r (\vec x + \vec u)$. Setting $\delta = n2^nC/r<n/2^n$, you'll get 
$$\frac 1{r^n}\int_{\|\vec u\|\le n2^n} e^{-\pi\|(\vec x+\vec u)/r\|^2} d\vec u =
\int_{\|\vec y-\vec x\|\le\delta} e^{-\pi\|\vec y\|^2}d\vec y < ke^{-\pi(\|\vec x\|-\delta)^2}\delta^n,$$
where the constant $k$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\Bbb R^n$. You should be able to get good estimates from this.

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you go from $e^{-\pi\|\vec y\|^2} \le e^{-\pi(\|\vec x\|-\delta)^2}\delta^n$. I'm assuming you used $\|\vec y-\vec x\|\le\delta$ but what kind of triangle inequality did you use and how come the delta came up as well when evaluating the integral?

Comment: The maximum value of the exponential occurs when $\vec y$ is the point in the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $\vec x$ closest to the origin. You can do this geometrically with a picture, or, indeed, you can use the reverse triangle inequality to say that $\|\vec y\|\ge \|\vec x\| - \delta$ in that ball. The $k\delta^n$  is the volume of the ball of radius $\delta$.

Comment: I see, thank you! the 1/r^n in front of the main integral, did't go anywhere, correct? Was that a typo or does it get absorbed in the bound with the volume of the ball * max of function?

Comment: The volume element $d\vec y$ is $1/r^n$ times the volume element $d\vec u$. We are using the change of variables formula.

Comment: Oh right, I completely missed that. Thank you!